# Bunny::NoFinalOctetError after some time without message

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, bunny

Using a rabbit mq installed with [official docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/) my worker fail with the exception Bunny::NoFinalOctetError after some time (around 40s) .

My worker code is :

```rb
require 'bunny'
require 'securerandom'

#TODO set host as parameter
rabbit_conn = Bunny.new
rabbit_conn.start

ch   = rabbit_conn.create_channel
q    = ch.queue("task", :durable => true)
ch.prefetch(1)

begin
  q.subscribe(:manual_ack => true, :block => true) do |delivery_info, properties, body|
        pp body 
    ch.ack(delivery_info.delivery_tag)
  end
rescue Interrupt => _
  rabbit_conn.close
end
```

I send data via the following code :

```rb
require "bunny"

conn = Bunny.new
conn.start

ch   = conn.create_channel
q    = ch.queue("task", :durable => true)

[
    'titi',
    'toto',
    'tata'
].each do |d|
    q.publish(d, :persistent => true)
end

sleep 1.0
conn.close
```

and after arround 40s I get the folllowing output in my worker

```
"titi"
"toto"
"tata"
E, [2017-10-18T15:56:55.938661 #28583] ERROR -- #<Bunny::Session:0x56182de41e48 guest@127.0.0.1:5672, vhost=/, addresses=[127.0.0.1:5672]>: Exception in the reader loop: Bunny::NoFinalOctetError: Frame doesn't end with � as it must, which means the size is miscalculated.
E, [2017-10-18T15:56:55.938890 #28583] ERROR -- #<Bunny::Session:0x56182de41e48 guest@127.0.0.1:5672, vhost=/, addresses=[127.0.0.1:5672]>: Backtrace: 
E, [2017-10-18T15:56:55.939037 #28583] ERROR -- #<Bunny::Session:0x56182de41e48 guest@127.0.0.1:5672, vhost=/, addresses=[127.0.0.1:5672]>:     /home/gg/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bunny-2.7.1/lib/bunny/transport.rb:255:in `read_next_frame'
E, [2017-10-18T15:56:55.939114 #28583] ERROR -- #<Bunny::Session:0x56182de41e48 guest@127.0.0.1:5672, vhost=/, addresses=[127.0.0.1:5672]>:     /home/gg/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bunny-2.7.1/lib/bunny/reader_loop.rb:68:in `run_once'
E, [2017-10-18T15:56:55.939175 #28583] ERROR -- #<Bunny::Session:0x56182de41e48 guest@127.0.0.1:5672, vhost=/, addresses=[127.0.0.1:5672]>:     /home/gg/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bunny-2.7.1/lib/bunny/reader_loop.rb:35:in `block in run_loop'
E, [2017-10-18T15:56:55.939233 #28583] ERROR -- #<Bunny::Session:0x56182de41e48 guest@127.0.0.1:5672, vhost=/, addresses=[127.0.0.1:5672]>:     /home/gg/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bunny-2.7.1/lib/bunny/reader_loop.rb:32:in `loop'
E, [2017-10-18T15:56:55.939288 #28583] ERROR -- #<Bunny::Session:0x56182de41e48 guest@127.0.0.1:5672, vhost=/, addresses=[127.0.0.1:5672]>:     /home/gg/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bunny-2.7.1/lib/bunny/reader_loop.rb:32:in `run_loop'
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from worker2.rb:21:in `<main>'
        4: from /home/gg/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bunny-2.7.1/lib/bunny/queue.rb:196:in `subscribe'
        3: from /home/gg/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bunny-2.7.1/lib/bunny/consumer_work_pool.rb:77:in `join'
        2: from /home/gg/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bunny-2.7.1/lib/bunny/consumer_work_pool.rb:77:in `each'
        1: from /home/gg/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bunny-2.7.1/lib/bunny/consumer_work_pool.rb:77:in `block in join'
/home/gg/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bunny-2.7.1/lib/bunny/consumer_work_pool.rb:77:in `join': caught an unexpected exception in the network loop: Frame doesn't end with � as it must, which means the size is miscalculated. (Bunny::NetworkFailure)
```

### Update about the network

I sniffed the network as it seems to be a malformed network packet. And indeed, the error is trigger after receiving a spécific packet.

Whireshark capture below, the error occur when receiving the packet 299.
[image]

Yet I have no idea what this packet is, nor why it is not handled by bunny.

## Update Github Ticket

I opened a ticket [here](https://github.com/ruby-amqp/bunny/issues/521)

Answer (score 0):

Turn out to be an issue on packet parsing.

The bug can be followed [her](https://github.com/ruby-amqp/bunny/issues/521#issuecomment-338022974)